# Save foreign key to database?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first, relation

I have a table Boards (but see it instead as a post). For each post/board I want to add possibility to vote and have created a table Votes. Every post can have a votenumber (eg 5) and every vote belongs to a post/board. I see it as it must be a one to one relationship. Correctly?

This is my models

```
public class Board
{
    [Key]
    public int MessageId { get; set; }
    public String Message { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Vote Vote { get; set; }
}

public class Vote
{
    [Key]
    public int? VoteId { get; set; }
    public int? Votes { get; set; }

    public Board Board { get; set; }

}
```

When I'am trying to create a new post `ModelState.IsValid` is false and no error, and can't see why when I debug.

This i my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "messageId,message,VoteId,Votes")] Board board)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Boards.Add(board);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I think it should be fine because I accept `null` for votes in my model.

I have manually added some data in both tables and I get a result on the web page with the code, but I cant create new posts.

Display posts/boards

```
    // GET: Boards
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var data = db.Boards.Include("Vote").ToList();

        return View(data);
    }
```

And the View.

```
@model IEnumerable<Klotterplank.Models.Board>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <ul>
                    <li class="board-blocks">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Message)</li>
                    <li class="board-blocks">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vote.Votes)</li>
                </ul>
            }
```

Comment: can each post really only have one vote? Or do you mean each user can only vote once on each post?

Comment: The result should be like this voting here on stackoverflow. One post, two arrows and a number. One post have one vote and each user can only vote once on each post. Guess I need to add the UserID.

Comment: so there are multiple votes per post, one per user. Then _in the UI_ is something which shows the _total number of votes_ per post. Personally I wouldn't store that total in the database - in relational terms it's redundant because you can calculate it based on the individual vote data (which you need, in order to link the votes to users and stop them voting twice, or to update if they change/remove their vote).

Comment: so assuming you have a posts table, and a users table, you then need a votes table which (in logical terms) sits in between them, where each row stores a Post ID and a User ID to link them together (and if you are doing +/- voting like on SO, a column to indicate how the user voted). The primary key would be the comination of UserID and PostID, thus preventing anyone voting twice. Querying the total number of votes per post would be a simple SUM() on the votes cast, filtered by the specific post ID.

Comment: Think I understand. You suggest a many to many relationship between users table and post table and use that extra association table as a voting table?

Comment: yes precisely. I can't think of a simpler structure off the top of my head. I can write that up into a proper answer if you like it

Comment: Yes please! I will accept it as correct answer even if it was not exactly what I asked for (but a better solution). I'am using asp.net Identity (when you start a new .net project with with registration and login possibility)

Comment: By chance, another user raised a similar issue in a chat room and I created [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VJSK1g) which you might be interested in - its by no means complete yet (and only the 'Up' button works at the moment) but it might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If every post has max. one vote and a vote belongs only to one post and the vote is only an int, I woud suggest to add the "Vote" as nullable int to "Post" so you don't even need a vote table